# 3 column layout not displaying properly when using <ul>

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

I have a 3 column layout that works fine when I use the

tag but all floats left when I used . I believe it has something to do with how wide my content is in each group but I don't know how to fix it! I've included screenshots and my code down below. Thanks!

Working with paragraph tag

Html:

```
<div class="anim">

         <div class="spacer">

            <div class="graphicOne">

                <p class="graphicHead"><img src="images/dollarSign.png" width="23px" height="47px"/></p>

                <p class="graphicBody">Look ma i'm road kill look at that, it's exactly three seconds before i honk your nose and pull your underwear over your head. we got no food we got no money and our pets heads are falling off! haaaaaaarry. we're going for a ride on the information super highway. your entrance was good, his was better. it's because i'm green isn't it! kinda hot in these rhinos.</p>
                <p class="graphLink"><a class="graphLink"  href="#windSection">Explore >></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="graphicThree">

                <p class="graphicHead"><img src="images/moreSign.png" width="40.25px" height="47px"/></p>

                <p class="graphicBody">Look ma i'm road kill look at that, it's exactly three seconds before i honk your nose and pull your underwear over your head. we got no food we got no money and our pets heads are falling off! haaaaaaarry. we're going for a ride on the information super highway. your entrance was good, his was better. it's because i'm green isn't it! kinda hot in these rhinos.</p>
                <p class="graphLink"><a class="graphLink"  href="#nuclearSection">Explore >></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="graphicTwo">

                <p class="graphicHead"><img src="images/mapMarker.png" width="28px" height="47px"/></p>

                <p class="graphicBody">Look ma i'm road kill look at that, it's exactly three seconds before i honk your nose and pull your underwear over your head. we got no food we got no money and our pets heads are falling off! haaaaaaarry. we're going for a ride on the information super highway. your entrance was good, his was better. it's because i'm green isn't it! kinda hot in these rhinos. </p>
                <p class="graphLink"><a  class="graphLink" href="#solarSection">Explore >></a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.anim {
    position:relative;
    display: table;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    height:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:16px;
}

.spacer{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;    
}

.graphicOne {
    display: table;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:300px;
}

.graphicTwo {
    display: table;
    width:30%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:300px;

}

.graphicThree {
    display: table;
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    height:300px;
}

.graphicHead {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:400;
    font-family: 'Doppio One', sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:underline;    
}

.graphicBody {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#666;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;   
}

.graphLink {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-family: 'Doppio One', sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:underline;   
}
```

Correct Display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMjCB.jpg

Non Working with unordered list tag

Html

```
<div class="anim">

         <div class="spacer">

            <div class="graphicOne">

                <p class="graphicHead"><img src="images/dollarSign.png" width="23px" height="47px"/></p>

                <p class="graphicBody">

                    <ul>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Install Cost:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Maintenance:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Tax Incentive:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Total Savings:</span> null</p></li>

                    </ul>

                </p>
                <p class="graphLink"><a class="graphLink"  href="#windSection">Explore >></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="graphicThree">

                <p class="graphicHead"><img src="images/moreSign.png" width="40.25px" height="47px"/></p>

                <p class="graphicBody">

                    <ul>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Best Location:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Needs:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Impact:</span> null</p></li>

                    </ul>

                </p>
                <p class="graphLink"><a class="graphLink"  href="#nuclearSection">Explore >></a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="graphicTwo">

                <p class="graphicHead"><img src="images/mapMarker.png" width="28px" height="47px"/></p>

                <p class="graphicBody">
                     <ul>

                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Best Location:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Needs:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Impact:</span> null</p></li>
                        <li><p class="graphText"><span class="bold">Impact:</span> null</p></li>

                    </ul>
                </p>
                <p class="graphLink"><a  class="graphLink" href="#solarSection">Explore >></a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.anim {
    position:relative;
    display: table;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    height:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:16px;
}

.spacer{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;    
}

.graphicOne {
    display: table;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:300px;
}

.graphicTwo {
    display: table;
    width:30%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:300px;

}

.graphicThree {
    display: table;
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    height:300px;
}

.graphicHead {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.graphicBody{
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#666;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;   
}

.graphText {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#666;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
}


.graphLink {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
    font-weight:700;
    font-family: 'Doppio One', sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:24px;   
}
```

non-working looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4pEd.jpg.

Any help would be great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `width: 100%` in your spacer class rule will make it work fine  http://jsbin.com/exARuNu/1/